# How to get warning message when closing CTabItem in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

How to add a listener in `CTabItem` for the `SWT.CLOSE` event?

I have tried `tab.addListener` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@avojak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3300205/avojak) mentioned, you can add a `DisposeListener` to each tab item to get notified when it was closed.

However, the `CTabFolder` also provides a [`CTabFolder2Listener`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCTabFolder2Listener.html). Its `close()` method is called *before* a tab item is closed. It even allows preventing closing the tab by setting the events `doit` flag to false.

For example:

```java
tabFolder.addCTabFolder2Listener(new CTabFolder2Adapter() {
  @Override
  public void close(CTabFolderEvent event) {
    event.doit = false; // disallow close
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you're looking for is [`CTabItem.addDisposeListener(DisposeListener)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html#addDisposeListener-org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener-) - inherited from [`Widget`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FWidget.html).

For example:

```
final CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(parent, SWT.NONE);
// ...
final CTabItem item = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("Item 1");
item.setShowClose(true);
item.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
    @Override
    public void widgetDisposed(final DisposeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }
});
```